# MySQL Server hitting 100% unexpectedly (Amazon AWS RDS)

Tags: mysql, aws

[image]

We've been struggling with this issue for months.

This week we upped our RDS instance to the highest performing instance and although the occurrences have reduced, we're still seeing our database suddenly hit 100% CPU Utilization.  This seems to come out of nowhere, sometimes at 2am, sometimes at midday.

I've ruled out a DOS - our site access logs show normal traffic.

I've ruled out `memcached` sudden death as hits and misses continue at a normal rate.

`SHOW PROCESSLIST` while we have issues reports about 500 queries in the queue. If I kill them off or restart the server, they keep coming back.  Eventually out of nowhere our server goes back to normal CPU utilization. Sometimes this takes up to 3 hours.

Our bad performing queries typically take 0.02 seconds to execute when the server is normal but while we're in this 100% CPU state, those queries never finish executing.

Does anybody know anything about MySQL query optimization? Could it be the server is deciding to use different indexes all of a sudden, which puts it into a spiral?

Comment: Have you enabled/checked the slow log? What kind of queries are the cause of this? Many simple statements/queries or a few complex ones?

Comment: it's a combination - i've checked the slow query log and there are a huge amount of queries in there the moment we enter this cycle.  some queries 10 seconds, some 1.5 minutes.  Those queries take next to no time to execute now though?

Comment: Only SELECTS or UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT statements as well?

Comment: both.  The UPDATES are just session table stuff, the SELECTS are all sorts of selects from across the whole website.  News, ForumDiscussions, Event information, Statistics - a combination of all of those.  It doesn't appear that there are row locking issues because the SHOW PROCESS LIST just reports those queries are executing.

Comment: Are the primary keys `auto_increment` in the tables? (or you have GUIDs as primary keys)?

Comment: Yeah they are.  Autoincrement, int values.  Nothing out of the ordinary there.

Comment: So we can get a clearer picture: 1) Does this sometimes-2AM-sometimes-midday scenario happen everyday? 2) Does it happen the same times everyday ? 3) Do you have any read replicas ? 4) Are all your tables InnoDB, MyISAM or a mixture of both ?

Comment: You say "SHOW PROCESSLIST" says the queries are "executing" -- do they really all have "executing" in the "State" column of the processlist?  Also, please post the exact server version from SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version';

Comment: Do you monitor io usage as well? Does your io stall or get flooded? Are you using InnoDB, MyISAM, or both?